# Drupal 7 - Map with multiple points

Tags: google-maps, drupal, module, drupal-7, maps

I'm setting up a Drupal 7 based "webservice" for my company.

I created a custom "Content Type" called POI that contains the informations about a single coordinate.

Now I'm looking for a module that can read from my object and show a Google Maps window with the driving route between all the points. (using Directions API).

Can somebody help me?

Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLayers seems to be the go-to mapping solution in Drupal 7. I have just barely started playing with it and it seems really powerful. All of the other modules I was able to find are basically out of commission, saying "OpenLayers does it better".

Comment: Thank you, today I'll take a tour :)